# I'm loading scripts with setTimeout, can you find a faster way?

Tags: javascript, performance, asynchronous

I have one file called **main.min.js**. This file has some parts which require the library **pixi.min.js**. The fastest way I can come up with to load these two parts is:

**HTML**

```
<script async src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pixi.js/3.0.11/pixi.min.js"></script>
<script async src="static/js/main.min.js"></script>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function waitForJS() {
        var shouldStop;

        if (typeof window.PIXI !== "undefined") {
            shouldStop = true;
        }

        if (shouldStop === true) {
            //PIXI has loaded
            ThePixiFunction();
            return;
        }

        setTimeout(waitForJS,30);
} waitForJS();
```

---

The reason I think this is the fastest way (for me) is because both files start loading at the same time, yet main.min.js starts executing before PIXI loads, and only the functions that need PIXI waits for it. Is there something about this I've overlooked? Or is there any better way of loading these two files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was stupid and I found a new way:

**HTML**

```
<script src="static/js/main.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pixi.js/3.0.11/pixi.min.js" onload="PIXILoaded();"></script>
```

**JS (in main.min.js)**

```
window.PIXILoaded = function() {
        initPixiFunction();
};
```

**Note that you should avoid globals**

Answer (score 0):

You could just split out the call to invoke your Pixi dependent behaviour into a separate file, then load them all normally:

```
<script src="static/js/main.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pixi.js/3.0.11/pixi.min.js"></script>
<script src="static/js/invokePIXIfunction.min.js></script>
```

Comment: Although that would work just fine I think that my last solution will be faster as it has fewer requests, and in practice the functionality will be the same. The only reason for this to be better is if the requestAnimationFrame() way uses too much resources for the user.